# Not working javascript: Dropdown menu filtering a List (Sharepoint 2007)

Tags: list, 2007, xslt-list-view-web-part, dropdown

I have a list with multiple MenuTypes (MenuA, MenuB)
I use a dropdown menu to filter these lists.

I get an info from the active directory, so I can filter which menuType will be shown to the user.

My issue is, when overriding the value selected using javascript

```
function setSelectValue (id, val) 
{
   document.getElementById(id).value = val;
}

if (role=="teamB") {    
   setSelectValue('ctl00$PlaceHolderTopNavBar$DropDownList1', 'MenuB');
}
else {
   setSelectValue('ctl00$PlaceHolderTopNavBar$DropDownList1', 'MenuB');
}
```

The value of the dropdown menu change to **MenuB**, but the list shown to the user is still MenuA